# MySQL for Each Value in Set

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, set

I have a `SET` column and have retrieved a value from it.

```
DECLARE types SET;
SET types = (SELECT...);
```

I'd like to iterate over `types` for each value of it.

How would I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need to loop through? Maybe a clever statement can do it in one step

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen got it! Thanks!

Comment: @juergend not sure about that but it's for a database that has 99.99% reads and 0.001% writes, so write speed doesn't matter too much to me.